# Having trouble with a non-breaking error

Tags: powershell

First off my code seems to work every time I run it even though I get an error returned. I'm curious to know what is happening and how to fix it.

My code is used to scrape metadata from an array of website links.

**Non-breaking error:**

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\test\websiteScrape.ps1:127 char:5
+     $List += [pscustomobject]@{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

**Code:**

```
$web = New-Object Net.WebClient
$web | Get-Member

function getMetaData($Array){
$fullArray = @()

foreach ($element in $Array){

    $metaString = $web.DownloadString($element)

    $metaArray = $metaString| Select-String -AllMatches '(meta name=".*?".+")|(a lang="fr" href=".*?")'  | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } 
       select -expa matches | select -expa value

       $fullArray += ,($element,$metaArray) 
       }

return $fullArray
}
#$Array is a System.Array and it holds a bunch of strings"links" to a website. 

$metaData = getMetaData $Array

$List = @()
for ($i=0; $i -le $metaData.length; $i++){

   $List += [pscustomobject]@{

   PageName = $metaData[$i][0]

   Description = [regex]::Replace($metaData[$i][1][1], 'meta name=".*?" content="(.*?)"', '$1');

   Creator = [regex]::Replace($metaData[$i][1][2], 'meta name=".*?" content="(.*?)"', '$1');

   Instituation = [regex]::Replace($metaData[$i][1][3], 'meta name=".*?" content="(.*?)"', '$1');

   Languague = [regex]::Replace($metaData[$i][1][4], 'meta name=".*?" content="(.*?)"', '$1');

   Subject =[regex]::Replace($metaData[$i][1][5], 'meta name=".*?" content="(.*?)"', '$1');

   Indentifier= [regex]::Replace($metaData[$i][1][6], 'meta name=".*?" content="(.*?)"', '$1');
   } 
}
List| Select-Object -Property PageName, Description| Export-Csv -path C:\Desktop\urlsAndMetaData.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I miss the definition of `$web`

Comment: @MartinBrandl i just added it, thanks.

Comment: also missing the declaration of `$List`

Comment: Can you provide one website link as an example?

Comment: @MartinBrandl Added $List, sorry quickly threw this together. Unfortunately the organization I am working for do not want me to be linking it on online.

Comment: Thats okay. So you want to export the page name and the content within the meta data tag?

Comment: @MartinBrandl That's exactly it, I have a bunch of other metatags I'm scraping I just did not want to clutter my code and keep it simple for you guys. I can add the rest of the code if you want to take a look at them.

Comment: If you add the other metadata you are trying to crap I can adopt my script to it

Comment: @MartinBrandl Done, thanks again!

Comment: can you provide one example  for each meta name line?(just write anything in the contet, im interested in the meta name)

Comment: @MartinBrandl 
<meta content="Businesses" name="dc.title">
<meta content="Lots Of text here" name="gc.description.long">
<meta content="John Doe" name="dc.creator">
<meta content="Hello World Inc." name="gc.institution">
<meta content="eng" name="dc.language">

Comment: I changed my answer. Now it will create a hashtable with the meta name as the key and the content as the value so you can easy access the metadata. The provided example should work as it is - just change the urls and give it a try. One thing to mention is that you rely on the order that meta name comes before content - you may have to switch these statements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your code correctly (unfortunately I don't have a link to test it), you can simplify your code a lot. This should do the same:

```
$web = New-Object Net.WebClient
$urls = @('www.firstlink.com', 'www.link2.com')

$regex = '<meta\s+name="([^"]+)" content="([^"]+)'

$urls | ForEach-Object {
    $webSiteContent = $web.DownloadString($_) 
    $metaData = @{}
    [regex]::Matches($webSiteContent, $regex) | ForEach-Object {
       $metaData.Add($_.Groups[1].Value, $_.Groups[2].Value)
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PageName = $_
        Description =  $metaData['gc.description.long']
        Creator = $metaData['dc.creator']
        Instituation = $metaData['dc.institution']
        Languague = $metaData['dc.language']
    }
} | Export-Csv -path C:\Desktop\urlsAndMetaData.csv -NoTypeInformation 

$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a shot. That code is beautiful, I'm pretty new to powershell and programming so I'm not very good at optimizing/minimizing my code.

Comment: @ImTrying Just a comment about my own learning in PowerShell: I found a coworker of mine writing very large scripts that had a lot of lines and complexity that I could reduce to far smaller scripts(4 lines instead of 40). After comparing the results, the smaller scripts produced identical results. However, the longer scripts made by my coworker worked almost ten times faster. Filtering out data you don't need was the biggest performance improvement in our situation. Not saying it's the same for your situation, but minimizing code length isn't always the best option.